# get term slug from current posts's custom taxonomy

Tags: taxonomy

I've been searching on this topic for 1 hour but I just can't seem to figure it out!

Im using this WP_Query to loop trough related posts and create clickable links:

```
<?php
        $currentID = get_the_ID();

        $args = array( 
          'post_type'       => 'nieuws',
          'orderby'         => 'date',
          'post__not_in'    => array($currentID),
          'nieuwssoort'     => current$term->slug,
          'posts_per_page'  => '7',
          );

        $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
      ?>

      <?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>
```

everything works great but I need to show post with the corresponding taxonomy term instead of all `nieuws` posts.
my taxonomy is called `nieuwssoort` and I need to dynamically fill in the term, I know I need to start with this probably: `$terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'nieuwssoort' )`, but just can't figure out the rest and how to include it in the `new WP_Query( $args )` arguments array so it will fill out the current posts's nieuwssoort term in `'nieuwssoort'     => ''`

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This gets the terms:

```
$terms = get_the_terms( get_the_ID(), 'nieuwssoort');
```

Then you check the result:

```
 $terms_ids = [];//you can set a default id here
    if(false !== $terms && !is_wp_error($terms)){
        foreach($terms as $term){
             $terms_ids[] = $term->term_id;
         }
    }
```

We check the result just in case.

Now, we have the values, let get them into the arguments:

```
$args = array( 
          'post_type'       => 'nieuws',
          'orderby'         => 'date',
          'post__not_in'    => array($currentID),
          'tax_query' => array(
                           array(
                            'taxonomy' => 'nieuwssoort',            
                            'terms'    => $terms_ids
                           ),
          ),

          'posts_per_page'  => '7',
      );
```

I can't test the code right now, but I think it should work.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks! What exactly are you doing in the second part where you check the result?

Comment: @BorisKamp, I'm checking if the `get_the_terms` worked and the result is right. You can [read here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_terms#Returns)